# Monitoring changes in text file with ajax (javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, server

I have done my research and cannot find an answer that works on this topic. I have a webpage right now with a text input field, every time that the input is changed it runs a function that writes data to a text file. The problem is that when I try to read the file and change an elements contents to the text file's contents, it always returns the same value. My function returns a value that my text file was a long while ago. Here is my code:

```js
function OpenFile(filePath) {
    var text = "NULL";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            text = ajax.responseText;
        }
    };
    ajax.open("POST", filePath, false);
    ajax.send();
    return text;
}

function WriteFile(filePath, content){
 var formdata = new FormData();
 formdata.append("content", content);
 var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.open("POST", filePath);
 ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(ajax.status == 200 && ajax.readyState == 4) {
      
  }
 };
 ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code that prevents me from reading the current contents of my file?

Comment: Maybe it happens because browser (or server) using cache. Go to dev panel (network) and check your post request to reading file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file may be cached by the browser's HTTP cache. Try appending a randomly-generated number as a query parameter to your request (your `filePath` variable).

For example,

```js
function OpenFile(filePath) {
    var text = "NULL";
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
            text = ajax.responseText;
        }
    };

    // HERE, append the query parameter with random number
    ajax.open("POST", filePath + '?' + Math.random(), false);

    ajax.send();
    return text;
}
```

If that was the problem, then [see here](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1680&bih=948&ei=PJR5XMz3NoOWsQWHhYL4Aw&q=clear%20http%20cache%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=clear%20http%20cache%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...710.710..1678...0.0..0.87.87.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.pT9hnbDbVQo) on more questions on how to manage clearing caches.